# joomla. search results on specified page

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

On main page is search module but there is no place to display search results. How to do that when you click on search button, results open on specified page in next window?

Joomla 1.7

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the core Joomla search module, when you click the search button it should load a new page with the search results. Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Not load when you click on a link shows: component/search/?searchword=gh&searchphrase=all&Itemid=102. But if you remove the the string 'component' will be as i need. How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the line need only home page template, as news template everything works correctly.

Comment: Do you have a link, I'm not sure I understand what is going wrong. It sounds like a setup problem.

Comment: You should post your solution and select it as the correct answer in case someone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue popped up all of a sudden (or perhaps I didn't scroll low enough during testing) in my joomla instalation and took me a while to figure it out. The behaviour was as follows: When you searched from the frontpage, result displayed above all the modules and elements of frontpage instead of a new page. If you searched from that page, a new page would be created (as it should). Issue was only when searching from frontpage.

The only difference in search from frontpage and non frontpage pages was the resulting url. It was exactly the same url but at the end the frontpage search was adding "&Itemid=435". If I removed "&Itemid=435" the results displayed in their own page.

Apparently, Joomla adds an "allegedly" random ID if you don't provide one in the module assigned to the search menu item. In Basic Options there's a "Set ItemID" field. Add the ID of the search menu item and voila! No more search results within the frontpage.